# How to fix SQL Exception happening only in android?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

I'm using xamarin forms to develop a cross-platform app.
As part of my app, I have a login page where the user enters his credentials and gets authenticated.
I'm using entity framework core and I'm connecting to a SQL server which is hosted on Azures cloud.
The code works and I can log in successfully, but only with IOS and UWP, if i try with Android I receive this exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>
```

If I continue the debugging I receive another exception which is:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Snix_PreLogin (provider: SNI_PN6, error: 31 - SNI_ERROR_31) Snix_PreLogin (provider: SNI_PN6, error: 31 - SNI_ERROR_31)
```

This is my Icommand:

```
LoginCommand = new Command(async () => await Login());
```

this is my method inside the view-model:

```
    private async Task Login()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_emailField) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_passwordField))
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "All fields must contain values.", "Ok");
        else
        {
            if (await DatabaseHandler.LoginUser(_emailField, _passwordField))
            {
                App.CurrentAccount = new UserAccount { Email = _emailField, Password = _passwordField };
                App.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
            }
            else
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "Email or password are incorrect.", "Ok");
        }
        IsBusy = false;
    }
```

and this is my method inside the DatabaseHandler:

```
    public static async Task<bool> LoginUser(string email, string password)
    {
        AzureContext AzureDb = new AzureContext();
        App.CurrentAccount = await AzureDb.UserAccounts.SingleOrDefaultAsync(account => account.Email == email && account.Password == password);
        return (App.CurrentAccount == null) ? false : true;
    }
```

Another thing worth mentioning is that when I comment out the IsBusy lines in the Login method which are responsible for the activity indicator, I no longer get an exception.
But, it's still not working, instead of an exception the UI just freezes for a long time and after it unfreezes nothing happens.

Help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
After playing around a little with the exception handling the full exception i get is this:

```
{System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Snix_PreLogin (provider: SNI_PN6, error: 31 - SNI_ERROR_31)Snix_PreLogin (provider: SNI_PN6, error: 31 - SNI_ERROR_31) ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Authentication failed, see inner exception.)
---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Unable to write data to the transport connection: Connection reset by peer.)
---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: Connection reset by peer. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection reset by peer  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags socketFlags) [0x00016] in <634e1667c20e48cfb6aa884228f8db67>:0   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size) [0x0009b] in <634e1667c20e48cfb6aa884228f8db67>:0    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size) [0x000e2] in <634e1667c20e48cfb6aa884228f8db67>:0   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SslOverTdsStream.WriteInternal (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count, System.Threading.CancellationToken token, System.Boolean async) [0x0017b] in <fb2d0bc6c8f7446eaa3eaa0ac572f8d3>:0    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00011] in <84c6975c2cbc47b489a2a76477d7a312>:0   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait (System.Int32 millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00043] in <84c6975c2cbc47b489a2a76477d7a312>:0   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait () [0x00000] in <84c6975c2cbc47b489a2a76477d7a312>:0   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SslOverTdsStream.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count) [0x0000f] in <fb2d0bc6c8f7446eaa3eaa0ac572f8d3>:0   at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.<InnerWrite>b__86_0 () [0x00006] in <634e1667c20e48cfb6aa884228f8db67>:0   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <84c6975c2cbc47b489a2a76477d7a312>:0   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in <84c6975c2cbc47b489a2a76477d7a312>:0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.InnerWrite (System.Boolean sync, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000d3] in <634e1667c20e48cfb6aa884228f8db67>:0   at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.ProcessOperation (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00196] in <634e1667c20e48cfb6aa884228f8db67>:0   at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.StartOperation (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0008b] in <634e1667c20e48cfb6aa884228f8db67>:0    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessAuthentication (System.Boolean runSynchronously, Mono.Net.Security.MonoSslAuthenticationOptions options, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00252] in <634e1667c20e48cfb6aa884228f8db67>:0    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00011] in <84c6975c2cbc47b489a2a76477d7a312>:0   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait (System.Int32 millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00043] in <84c6975c2cbc47b489a2a76477d7a312>:0   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait () [0x00000] in <84c6975c2cbc47b489a2a76477d7a312>:0   at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) [0x0003d] in <634e1667c20e48cfb6aa884228f8db67>:0   at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.AuthenticateAsClient(string,System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection,System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols,bool) at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost) [0x00007] in <634e1667c20e48cfb6aa884228f8db67>:0   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost) [0x00006] in <634e1667c20e48cfb6aa884228f8db67>:0   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNITCPHandle.EnableSsl (System.UInt32 options) [0x0000c] in <fb2d0bc6c8f7446eaa3eaa0ac572f8d3>:0   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNIProxy.EnableSsl (System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNIHandle handle, System.UInt32 options) [0x00000] in <fb2d0bc6c8f7446eaa3eaa0ac572f8d3>:0 ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Unable to write data to the transport connection: Connection reset by peer.)
---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: Connection reset by peer. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection reset by peer  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags socketFlags) [0x00016] in <634e1667c20e48cfb6aa884228f8db67>:0   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size) [0x0009b] in <634e1667c20e48cfb6aa884228f8db67>:0    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size) [0x000e2] in <634e1667c20e48cfb6aa884228f8db67>:0   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SslOverTdsStream.WriteInternal (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count, System.Threading.CancellationToken token, System.Boolean async) [0x0017b] in <fb2d0bc6c8f7446eaa3eaa0ac572f8d3>:0    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00011] in <84c6975c2cbc47b489a2a76477d7a312>:0   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait (System.Int32 millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00043] in <84c6975c2cbc47b489a2a76477d7a312>:0   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait () [0x00000] in <84c6975c2cbc47b489a2a76477d7a312>:0   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SslOverTdsStream.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count) [0x0000f] in <fb2d0bc6c8f7446eaa3eaa0ac572f8d3>:0   at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.<InnerWrite>b__86_0 () [0x00006] in <634e1667c20e48cfb6aa884228f8db67>:0   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <84c6975c2cbc47b489a2a76477d7a312>:0   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in <84c6975c2cbc47b489a2a76477d7a312>:0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.InnerWrite (System.Boolean sync, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000d3] in <634e1667c20e48cfb6aa884228f8db67>:0   at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.ProcessOperation (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00196] in <634e1667c20e48cfb6aa884228f8db67>:0   at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.StartOperation (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0008b] in <634e1667c20e48cfb6aa884228f8db67>:0    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessAuthentication (System.Boolean runSynchronously, Mono.Net.Security.MonoSslAuthenticationOptions options, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00252] in <634e1667c20e48cfb6aa884228f8db67>:0 <---  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor (System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential credential, System.Object providerInfo, System.String newPassword, System.Security.SecureString newSecurePassword, System.Boolean redirectedUserInstance, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, System.Data.SqlClient.SessionData reconnectSessionData, System.Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) [0x00163] in <fb2d0bc6c8f7446eaa3eaa0ac572f8d3>:0   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection (System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions options, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, System.Object poolGroupProviderInfo, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool pool, System.Data.Common.DbConnection owningConnection, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions) [0x00144] in <fb2d0bc6c8f7446eaa3eaa0ac572f8d3>:0   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection (System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool pool, System.Data.Common.DbConnection owningObject, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions options, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions) [0x0000c] in <fb2d0bc6c8f7446eaa3eaa0ac572f8d3>:0   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject (System.Data.Common.DbConnection owningObject, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) [0x00184] in <fb2d0bc6c8f7446eaa3eaa0ac572f8d3>:0   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest (System.Data.Common.DbConnection owningObject, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) [0x00040] in <fb2d0bc6c8f7446eaa3eaa0ac572f8d3>:0   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection (System.Data.Common.DbConnection owningObject, System.UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, System.Boolean allowCreate, System.Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal& connection) [0x000a4] in <fb2d0bc6c8f7446eaa3eaa0ac572f8d3>:0   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen () [0x00092] in <fb2d0bc6c8f7446eaa3eaa0ac572f8d3>:0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync (System.Boolean errorsExpected, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000f9] in <c486d2adb419411a9a11f423095801e5>:0   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Boolean errorsExpected) [0x0009b] in <c486d2adb419411a9a11f423095801e5>:0   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1+AsyncEnumerator[T].BufferlessMoveNext (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext _, System.Boolean buffer, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00098] in <c486d2adb419411a9a11f423095801e5>:0   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult] (TState state, System.Func`4[T1,T2,T3,TResult] operation, System.Func`4[T1,T2,T3,TResult] verifySucceeded, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00089] in <70780d57b1e644f080d08b633fa994bf>:0   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1+AsyncEnumerator[T].MoveNext (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00135] in <c486d2adb419411a9a11f423095801e5>:0   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.SingleOrDefault_[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[T] source, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000d7] in <afef21b57ad6402f8df4c5299ba699e2>:0   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider+TaskResultAsyncEnumerable`1+Enumerator[T].MoveNext (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00075] in <e66a1f96e9734a7fac7cea0901022728>:0   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable+SelectEnumerableAsyncIterator`2[TSource,TResult].MoveNextCore (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000a6] in <afef21b57ad6402f8df4c5299ba699e2>:0   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable+AsyncIterator`1[TSource].MoveNext (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00101] in <afef21b57ad6402f8df4c5299ba699e2>:0   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider+ExceptionInterceptor`1+EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor[T].MoveNext (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00143] in <e66a1f96e9734a7fac7cea0901022728>:0   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteSingletonAsyncQuery[TResult] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryContext queryContext, System.Func`2[T,TResult] compiledQuery, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.IDiagnosticsLogger`1[TLoggerCategory] logger, System.Type contextType) [0x000d6] in <e66a1f96e9734a7fac7cea0901022728>:0   at Life_Programmer.Services.DatabaseServices.DatabaseHandler.LoginUser (System.String email, System.String password) [0x00108] in C:\Users\Meydan\source\repos\Life_Programmer\Life_Programmer\Life_Programmer\Services\DatabaseServices\DatabaseHandler.cs:43 ClientConnectionId:7453d528-808d-4249-b0db-ee7d31c86008}
```

EDIT2: 
If I handle the exception so the application won't crash, then after the first try it works as expected.
So the problem occurs only on the first login try, and only with Android.

Comment: instead of catching the exception in the debugger, try wrapping the operation in a try/catch and writing the exception detail out to the console

Comment: I tried that already, I didn't get new information.

Comment: what was the exception Message?  Did you check for an InnerException?

Comment: InnerException - System.IO.IOException

Message: Snix_PreLogin (provider: SNI_PN6, error: 31 - SNI_ERROR_31)
Snix_PreLogin (provider: SNI_PN6, error: 31 - SNI_ERROR_31)

Comment: EDIT: another message : Unable to write data to the transport connection: Connection reset by peer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the way my app communicates with the database and the problem got solved, instead of communicating from my app directly to the database I'm communicating to it through a web API.